# Check if varibale is defined (dynamic Var!)

Tags: javascript

How can i check if a dynamic var is defined?

```
var num=2;
var foo2=true

if (typeof ('foo'+num)!="undefined"){
return 1
}
```

Comment: While **technically** you could see if a `foo2` variable existed by using `eval`, dynamic variables are poor practice, and using `eval` is best avoided. See the linked question's answers for what to do instead (basically: use an array or an object). (Using `eval` for it: ```let exists = (() => { try { (0, eval(`foo${num}`)); return true; } catch { return false; } })();``` But don't do that.)

Comment: Thanks for this info. But without eval it is not possible to check

Comment: Can somebody else Vote for a "Reopen" of this topic? This linked dublicate Topic is not satisfy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `eval` statement.

```js
var num = 2;

var con = 'foo' + num
console.log(eval("typeof " + con + " === 'undefined'"))
```

Comment: That would be fooled into thinking it wouldn't exist if it existed and had the value `undefined`.

Comment: And this is an often-repeated duplicate question.